# ImportError when importing python file from parent folder

Tags: python

I am encountering error:
`ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`
when trying to import `wrapper.py`

Folder structure:

```
├───clashAPI
│   │   config.py
│   │   implementation.py
│   │   wrapper.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   └───__pycache__
│           config.cpython-39.pyc
│           implementation.cpython-39.pyc
│
├───dataProcessing
│       members.py
│       __init__.py
│
└───telegram
```

both `__init__.py` files are empty.

members.py:

```
from ..clashAPI.wrapper import apiWrapper

class memberProcessing:
    apiClient = None

    def getMemberDonations(self,tag):
        members = self.piClient.getAllClanMembersByClanTag(self, tag)
        for member in members:
            print(member["name"])

    def __init__(self):
        self.apiClient = apiWrapper()

process = memberProcessing()
process.getMemberDonations("#2QQL2VYQ2")
```

wrapper.py:

```
from implementation import *
from config import *

class apiWrapper:
    apiObject = None

    def getAllClanMembersByClanTag(self, tag):
        return self.apiObject.getClanMembersByClanTag(tag)
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.apiObject = clashAPI(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these articles:
[Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3)
and [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time).
The issue has to do with relative imports, and the difference between modules and scripts. Try changing `PYTHONPATH` as explained in the articles, or run in the command line

```
python3 -m dataProcessing.members
```

or whatever your path to members.py is.